# How to stop RVM interfering with JRuby

Tags: java, ruby, rvm, jruby, warbler

I have used Warbler to create a Jar file from my Ruby source. I also have RVM installed. The behaviour of the jar differs depending on which Ruby version RVM is using: if I `rvm use jruby` then the jar works normally, but if I `rvm use 2.2` then running the jar prints these warning messages to the console:

```
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
```

And if I `rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p484` then running the jar actually fails:

```
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.2.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.2.1
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.6.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.6.2
Ignoring executable-hooks-1.3.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine executable-hooks --version 1.3.2
Ignoring gem-wrappers-1.2.7 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine gem-wrappers --version 1.2.7
Ignoring nokogiri-1.6.2.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine nokogiri --version 1.6.2.1
Ignoring unf_ext-0.0.7.1 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine unf_ext --version 0.0.7.1
NameError: uninitialized constant Nokogiri::XERCES_VERSION
 const_missing at org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2733
       to_hash at /vagrant/myproject!/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2-java/lib/nokogiri/version.rb:73
       ...
```

If I run the jar on computer without rvm installed, it works fine.

What is causing this, and how do I stop RVM from interfering with my jar?

Comment: maybe you should try rbenv https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

Answer (score 2):

its not simply RVM to blame, the system Ruby installation might have interfered as well ... unset `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` environment variables so that they're not used.

if it's a .war you can also try isolating completely by the embed JRuby to start a Ruby runtime with an empty ENV using `jruby.runtime.env=false` system property (or app context init parameter)

for packaged .jar archives use **config.override_gem_home** (should work with .war as well)

Comment: Unsetting GEM_PATH worked! It isn't a .war so I can't use `jruby.runtime.env`. Do you know if there's some configuration option to prevent the jar from attempting to use the GEM_PATH environment variable at all?

Comment: @fblundun yes ... updated the answer with `config.override_gem_home`